# Footer is not staying on bot when dynamically height is altered

Tags: php, html, css

My Footer is working fine in every page, it is always on the bottom of the page. However, with this page where images are dynamically added to the page depending on how many images are on the server, the Footer is overlapping the images if there are too many images.

CSS image container

```
.imgBot{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 500px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    left: 70px;
}
```

Page layout head/body/footer

```
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:white;
    padding:10px;
}
#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background:#EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    (pointless code here)
    <div class='imgBot'>
        <?php echo $imgBox;?>
    </div>
    <?php include "../footer.php"?>
</div>
```

PHP

```
while ($row = $sqlQuery->fetch_array()) {
        $childID = $row['ID'];
        $childName = $pID . "_" . $childID . ".jpg";
        $imgBox .= "<img src='../ProductImages/ChildImages/$childName' 
width='200px' height='200px'>";
}
```

Comment: dollars to donuts `position: absolute;` is your problem.

Comment: u mean the position: absolute in the imgBot? i changed that and it didnt work same thing

Comment: you mean in the footer. well if i change it to relative. the footer will go in the middle of some pages that has content up to the middle

Comment: Better give z-index:10;something to your footer.

Comment: Tried that didnt work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't konw why you have so many attributes in your css and how your real final file will result.
Anyway, a basic version of what you need can be accomplished this way:

Style:

```
<style>
    #container {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    }
    #header {
    background:white;
    padding:10px;
    }
    #body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:40px;   /* Height of the footer */
    }
    #footer {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    height:40px;   
    width:100%;
    margin-top:10px;
    background:#EBEBEB;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .imgBot{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class='imgBot'>

    </div>      
</div>  
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

PHP (just as example, change the number of rows to see how it fits):

```
<?php 
    $row=0;
    while ($row <20) {
        $imgBox= "<img src='../ProductImages/ChildImages/' 
        width='200px' height='200px'>";
        echo $imgBox;
        $row++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why float elements to the left? thanks i will try this.

Comment: Give a look at this good article: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/